# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'cid1' was corrupted

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to C programming and am currently taking classes in college. I've come across this error and am unsure of how to fix it after hours of google. I'm working on creating a program that prints a grade report and keep running into this error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{   char Name[20];
    char cid1[5]="", cid2[5]="", cid3[5]="", cid4[5]="", cid5[5]="", cid6[5]="";
    char Description1[20]="", Description2[20]="", Description3[20]="", Description4[20]="", Description5[20]="", Description6[20]="";
    int hrs1 = 0, hrs2=0, hrs3=0, hrs4=0, hrs5=0, hrs6=0;
    char grade1[1]="",grade2[1]="",grade3[1]="",grade4[1]="",grade5[1]="",grade6[1]="";

    printf("Enter Students Name ");
    gets(Name);

    printf("Enter Class ID ");
    scanf("%s", &cid1);

    printf("Enter Class Description ");
    gets(Description1);

    printf("%s", Name);
    printf("%s", cid1);
    printf("%s", Description1);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What values do you enter?

Comment: Why do you have the C++ tag if this is C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only read as much as the arrays will support. If you declare a char array to have 5 bytes (`char cid1[5]`), then you can enter at most 4 characters (the 5th is a null terminator). If you enter more, you will corrupt memory and get that message.

`gets` is also a horrendously insecure function to use for reading strings from input because it is impossible to avoid a buffer overflow. **Never** use it. Use `fgets` instead with `stdin`.

Comment: Note that `scanf` with `%s` (and no length specification, i.e., `%s` instead of `%4s`) is just as unsafe as `gets`.

Comment: @nneonneo That worked! And I'll switch to using fgets, thanks! One more quick question though, when debugging and entering my information, I am unable to enter my class description. It doesn't even give me the prompt. Once I press enter after entering my cid1, it prints my name and cid1 along with a blank space where the description should go

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%s", &cid1);
```

You need to call:

```
scanf("%s", cid1);
```

And your array is declared with a size of `5` elements so if you pass more than `4` characters (you have to count the trailing `\0`) you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Shouldn't matter. The pointer addresses are the same, but the types are different.

Comment: @nneonneo: You're right that it won't make a difference with most implementations, but just for the record, it officially does cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem, but right off the bat I can see there's a problem with string allocation.

Remember, strings in C are stored as a series of char values, terminated by a 0.  That means that a five-digit course name will require six chars to hold it... something like { 'C', 'S', '1', '0', '1', '\0' }.  That also means that a single digit grade stared as a string will require two chars.

Since the gets() function appends that zero on to the end of the string, your grade1[1] array (as one example) is being overflowed.  It is declared to hold one char, but two chars are being written to it.  That can, among other things, end up corrupting your stack.  I would increase the size of all your arrays by at least one more char.

Another problem is that you have no error-checking, so that it's possible that somebody will enter a name more than 20 characters and cause errors, but that's probably just because you're still learning basics.  In 'real' code, you probably would never use gets().